# Why doesn't assignment to Symbol.iterator throw an error?

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-symbol

In Chrome on Windows, I have this in the console:

```
> Symbol.iterator
< Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
> Symbol.iterator = "Hello!";
< "Hello!"
> Symbol.iterator;
< Symbol(Symbol.iterator)
```

So Symbol.iterator (thankfully) doesn't change, but why doesn't my attempt to assign to it throw an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sloppy mode, the failed assignment doesn't cause an exception. Use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) instead:

```
(function(){ "use strict"; Symbol.iterator = "Hello" }())
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property `iterator` of function `function Symbol() { [native code] }`

Comment: Even in "sloppy" mode, I never would have imagined they'd let something like that go! What a nightmare.